# Sort pandas dataframe where values are date (how to create pivot_table without aggregation)

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a dataframe with columns A, B, C, and Date. I don't care about C. I want to create a pivot table where I have A in the first column, then B, and then in the third column I want to have the Dates.

I get an error saying

> DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

I'm merely looking to do something that can be done easily in excel pivot table.

I also need the dates to be sorted.

Let's say my initial df is:

```
A         B          C        D
apple     sweet      funny    2019-07-02
apple     sweet      dummy    2016-11-25
apple     sweet      dff      2017-09-01
apple     sweet               NaT
orange    sour                2020-01-01
orange    sour       hhhg     2020-12-12
banana    neither             2015-01-01
```

I want to get:

```
    A         B         D
apple     sweet      NaT
          sweet      2016-11-25
          sweet      2017-09-01
          sweet      2019-07-02
orange    sour       2020-01-01
          sour       2020-12-12
banana    neither    2015-01-01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you want to do is just drop `C` and set `A`/`B` as index:

```
df.set_index(['A', 'B'])[['D']]
```

output:

```
                         D
A      B                  
apple  sweet    2019-07-02
       sweet    2016-11-25
       sweet    2017-09-01
       sweet           NaT
orange sour     2020-01-01
       sour     2020-12-12
banana neither  2015-01-01
```

*NB. you might want to sort the values, but how is not clear. If sorting by ascending `D`, NaT should be last, not first*

Alternatively to have everything as columns:

```
df.sort_values(['A', 'B', 'D']).drop('C', axis=1)
```